# Как увеличить зону клика ссылки?

Tags: html, css

Использую ползунок (input type range).Дело в том, что по макету он в `1px` и все идеально, только вот кликнуть по нему очень сложно, надо попасть в этом самый 1px. Можете, пожалуйста, посоветовать как увеличить его зону?

Comment: добавьте ему padding`ом этой зоны.
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  padding: 10px;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Без кода, могу предложить добавить невидимый `before`(подкрасила цветом, чтобы видно было область, вам этот цвет просто убрать нужно):

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin:50px auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  background: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.06);//цвет убрать
}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#"></a>
```